# Explanation for the proof of Ptolemy-inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

In the [book](http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of *linear algebra* by Werner Greub, at page $190$, it is given the proof of the *Ptolemy-inequality*,

$$|x-y| |z| \leq |y-z| |x| + |z-x||y|,$$
where $x,y,z$ are in a real inner product space, and |.| is the *Euclidian* norm.

So how can we prove that if at least one of the vectors is zero, then the inequality holds ?

In case you want to see the complete proof,

[image]

**Edit:**

Right now, **I only need to prove $|x||z| = |xz|$.**

Comment: "In the proof, it first consider the trivial case where all of the vectors are zero, and says that the equality holds." Where ? He says "if one of the three vectors is zero".

Comment: @ama after some reading, I stop reading and start to image things.It is not the first time that I have read something completely different from its original.Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: @ama but of course even though I have read wrong, there is a question that how can we prove that trivial case.

Comment: From the proof it seems that $|x|=\sqrt{(x,x)}$ where $(x,y)$ is a bilinear inner product and from this it is immediate that $|xy|=|x||y|$.

Comment: @Somos Apparently, I am not able to see how it is an immediate result, so stating that it directly follows is, sort of, meaningless unless you also state that why it is a direct result.

Comment: The property of bilinearity implies $(ax,by)=ab(x,y)$ where $a$ and $b$ are scalars. In your case, you need to use $|x-y||z| = |x|z|-y|z||$ instead.

Comment: @Somos then we need $|z|^2$, not $|z|$ in that case, but right now I'm specifically asking $|x||z| = |xz|$ ?

Comment: If $x$ and $z$ are vectors, then what is $xz$?

Comment: @Somos I have no idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mainly asked this question because I thought the proof was incomplete, but thanks to @ama's comment, I realised what I have read wrong, so for the rest of the problem, i.e at least one of the vectors is zero case,

Since $|- a| = |a|$ by definition, when we assume one of them is zero, the inequality leaves it place to equality, so the statement holds.

Comment: Maybe you read the question one more. The demonstration doesn't presume one of the numbers is 0. Only the trivial case handles with x=0 or y=0 or z=0.

Comment: @ama I didn't get it what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are scalar (not vectors), then:
$$|a+b|\le |a|+|b|.$$
Thus:
$$|x-y|=|x-z+z-y|\le |x-z|+|z-y|,$$
$$|x-y||z|=|xz-yz|=|xy-zx+zy-xy|\le |xy-zx|+|zy-xy|=|y-z||x|+|z-x||y|.$$

Comment: Then you also need to prove that $|x-y| |z| = |xz - yz|$.

Comment: if we can show that $|x| |z| = |xz|$, the rest is obvious, but I have no idea how to show $|x| |z| = |xz|$. I mean It doesn't come from its definition.

Comment: What does $xz$ even mean? These are vectors, not complex numbers!