# Prove that $|x-y||z| = |y-z||x| + |z-x||y|$ holds iff $x,y,z,0$ are contained on a circle such that the pairs $x,y$ and $z,0$ seperate each other

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, normed-spaces, inner-products

In the book of *Linear Algebra* by Werner Greub, at page 191 Q.3, it is asked that,

> Prove that $|x-y||z| = |y-z||x| + |z-x||y|$ holds iff  $x,y,z,0$ are
>   contained on a circle such that the pairs $x,y$ and $z,0$ seperate
>   each other

I basically couldn't do much thing but the question is really interesting, and I'm sure that there will be good answers both geometrically and axiomatically.

**Edit:**

Note that this is a direct result of [Ptolemy-inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368815/explanation-for-the-proof-of-ptolemy-inequality?rq=1), but still can't see the result.

**Edit2:**

Our vector space is a real inner product space.

Answer (score 4):

This means that in the complex plane, $x^{-1}$, $y^{-1}$ and $z^{-1}$
are collinear with $z^{-1}$ between $x^{-1}$ and $y^{-1}$. Therefore
$$|x^{-1}-y^{-1}|=|x^{-1}-z^{-1}|+|z^{-1}-y^{-1}|.$$

Comment: I cannot see that implication, could you collaborate on that point ?

Comment: Plus, what does $x^{-1}$ represent ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas the reciprocal of the complex number $x$.